# Best Open Source WSDL/XML Editor for Java

Tags: java, xml, wsdl, xml-editor

Which is considered as the best free WSDL visual editor? I am working in java if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse try [Eclipse Web Tools Platform Project](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project_summary.php?projectid=webtools), it's good at my point of view and sufficient for me.

Comment: It's really great, I can recommend it. However as of today it does not support WSDL 2.0.

Comment: The eclipse XML editor is fine if your XML files are relatively small, but I have had serious performance problems when the files get into the MB range.